# How to convert SObject to JSON in APEX or the reverse

Tags: apex, json

I have a stored data as JSON and I want to convert it to object in order to fill a `<apex:pageBlockTable>` with it.

Is there a library I can use like `GSON` library ? Or what is the best thing to do ?

Answer (score 8):

Apex has a [native JSON support](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_class_System_Json.htm)

You can use the `serialise` and `deserialise` methods.

[Here is a round-trip example](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_json_json.htm?search_text=serialize) and if that doesn't work for you or you have more complex data, consider using the [JSON parser](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_class_System_JsonParser.htm)

[Also have a look at these examples](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Getting_Started_with_Apex_JSON)

Comment: But in this serialization process, the JSON structure has to suit the object structure. I want to serialize JSON data to an object without specifying attributes to suit the JSON data. Exactly like JavaScript. is it possible ?

Comment: @HasanKhatib The [serializeUntyped](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_class_System_Json.htm#apex_System_Json_deserializeUntyped) method allows this.