# How to build a Apex Class to handle a JSON format in my example

Tags: apex, json

I want to build a custom sync framework and combine serval object's data to a Json string. For example

```
List<Account> accounts = [select Id, Name, ... from Account where ...];
```

The sOBject is dynamic, it can be Account, Contact or CustomObject__c and the fields is also dynamic. the field between select and from clause is flexible. That means I don't know there will be how many fields. I want to convert the select result to this format:

```
   {
   "records": [
    {
        "values": [
            "00190000014IoCoAAK | 00081 | Super Mart | ...",
            "00190000014EoCAABK | 00082 | Test Mart | ...",
        ],
        "objName": "Account",
        "fields": "Id,AccountNumber,Name, ..."
    },
    {
        "values": [
            "0039000001JDBt7AAH | 00190000014IoCoAAK | Ues1 | ..."
        ],
        "objName": "Contact",
        "fields": "Id,AccountId,Name, ..."
    }
 ] 
}
```

How can I build a Apex calss to handle this Json?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert SObject to JSON in APEX or the reverse](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/54944/how-to-convert-sobject-to-json-in-apex-or-the-reverse)

Comment: It's different question,  in my example, I need to know how to build this class and how to process the very dynamic json format.

Comment: I need someone who can give me some demo code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the sort of code I would write for this:

```
public class Records {

    public Record[] records;

    public Records() {
        records = new Record[] {};
        records.add(new Record(Account.SObjectType, new SObjectField[] {
                Account.Id,
                Account.Name,
                ...
                }));
        records.add(new Record(Contact.SObjectType, new SObjectField[] {
                Contact.Id,
                Contact.AccountId,
                Contact.Name,
                ...
                }));
    }

    public String toJsonString() {
        return JSON.serializePretty(this);
    }
}

public class Record {

    public String objName;
    public String fields;
    public String[] values;

    public Record(SObject sob, SObjectType type, SObjectField[] fields) {

        objName = String.valueOf(type);

        String[] names = new String[] {};
        for (SObjectField field : fields) {
            names.add(String.valueOf(field));
        }
        fields = String.join(names, ',');

        for (SObject sob : Database.query(''
                + ' select ' + fields
                + ' from ' + objName
                + ' ...'
                )) {
            String[] rowValues = new String[] {};
            for (SObjectField field : fields) {
                rowValues.add(String.valueOf(sob.get(field)));
            }
            values.add(String.join(rowValues, ' | '));
        }
    }
}
```

where the string would be created using:

```
String jsonString = new Records().toJsonString();
```

The custom formatting is handled by Apex code and then the standard serialize method handles the standard JSON conversion.

Comment: If there are so many object and data to process, it will reach the HeadSize limit, How can I process it?

Comment: @BruceYue To avoid the heap size limit and other governor limits you will have to limit the number of records you work with at once and use multiple requests.

Comment: If I have a child query in the Database.query(), and I also want to build the child object's data as the example I posted, How can I do?

Comment: @BruceYue Add a class for the child object and define a field in Record `Child[] children`. Then in Records constructor you can use [getSObject](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm#apex_System_SObject_getSObjects) and use that data to create the child objects.

Comment: Thanks Keith, but this is not what i'm asking, I didn't want to break my current json structure. Just want to  use a child query and build data to the records, object  with name, fields and values.